# How can I select all fields in a join that I can use later with other query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

This is my join:

```
var jCorsi = from t in db.Table1
             join j in db.Table2 on t.IDCourse equals j.IDCourse
             select new { t, j };
```

and I need (later with other query) to be able to use fields of both table.
Example:

```
var testx = (from j in jCorsi
             group j by j.IDCourse  into g
```

but it says "doesn't find a definition of `j.IDCourse`", even if I've selected t and j.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
var testx = (from j in jCorsi
             group j by j.t.IDCourse  into g
             select ...
```

(`j.t.` in stead of `j.`)

Maybe it's better to make it more explicit:

```
var jCorsi = from t in db.Table1
             join j in db.Table2 on t.IDCourse equals j.IDCourse
             select new { Table1 = t, Table2 = j };

var testx = (from x in jCorsi
             group x by x.Table1.IDCourse  into g
             select ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var jCorsi = from t in table1
                 join j in table2 on t.IDCourse equals j.IDCourse
                 select new { t, j };

    var testx = from j in jCorsi
                group j by j.t.IDCourse into g
                select g;
```